# Pyspark split string then multiply

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any way to do the following in about two or three lines of code in pyspark?

```
c1
23:34
00:30

c1  c2
23  34
00  30
```

Then we multiply the hour for 3600 and the minute for 60 and sum the tables.

```
c1 
84840
1800
```

Basically a conversion from hours:minutes in string to seconds in numeric.

Comment: Yes, there is. Did you try anything?

Comment: @philantrovert I mostly tried splitting the values, and creating new columns each with Hour and minute, then I had to change the type of these columsn to Integer and finaly I was trying to figure out an udf to multiply and sum the columns.

The thing is I have multiple hours columns so this would probably attack any performance (using withColumns for every new column and all).

Comment: how did you get `2040`?

Comment: @mtoto 00*3600 + 30 *60 = 1800...yap multiplied for 34 instead, changing it.

Comment: It's basic arithmetic. You really don't need a UDF. Something like `split(col('c1') , ':').getItem(0)*3600 + split(col('c1'), ':')*60`. That's it.

Comment: I get a type mismatch due to the string splits resulting in strings, let's see if i can use python to turn them into integers.

Edit: Nope int() doesn't work since it would need to apply to the column.

Comment: Oh hang on, forgot the getItem(1), still the column is not appearing after:
         `df= df.withColumn('c2', splitting)`, spliting being the split code.

Holy shit am I dumb forgot was inside a method, so the df wasn't coming outside of it! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `split()`, and subsequently perform the calculation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

df.withColumn("test", split("c1", ":")[0] * 3600 +
                      split("c1", ":")[1] * 60)
```